# VBA macro to list all the combinations in a row

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I'm relatively new to VBA and am currently trying to write a macro that is  above my abilities.

Basically, I'm look to list all the possible combinations within the row of the table so for example:

```
Gas Diamonds Graphite Graphene
Red Blue Black
```

Would become

```
Gas Diamonds
Gas Graphite
Gas Graphene
Diamonds Graphite
Diamonds Graphene
Graphite Graphene
Red Blue
Red Black
Blue Black
```

The table has a maximum of 5 columns.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried writing any code? Posting an example of code you have tried will give us the ability to provide you with more helpful feedback. There are several examples of code on this forum that would be a good jumping off point for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the number of elements in one column with

```
Dim Lastcolumn
With ActiveSheet
   LastColumn = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With
```

Loop through the number of combinations and display with "Cells(x,y)"